# The device is incompatible for this app (cordova)

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, google-play

I developed an app for android using cordova in visual studio and the app was working fine in all the devices. But when I uploaded the same in the playstore, I couldn't find it in the list in some devices (especially in samsung and nexus). I entered the link in the address bar to find the app in those devices. But I couldn't install it since it says "The device is incompatible for this app". This is the code for config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns:cdv="cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps" id="com.inb.xxxxx" android-versionCode="10" version="3.3.0.2" xmlns="www.w3.org/ns/widgets">
  <name>App name</name>
  <description> Apache Cordova to help you build an app that targets multiple mobile platforms: Android, iOS, Windows, and Windows Phone.</description>
  <author href="abc.com" email="info@abcd.com">test Cordova Team</author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="11" />
  <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="22" />
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="22" />
  <vs:plugin name="com.rjfun.cordova.sms" version="1.0.3" />
  <vs:plugin name="com.teamnemitoff.phonedialer" version="0.3.0" />
  <vs:plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" version="0.0.1" />
  <vs:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin" version="2.4.0" />
  <vs:plugin name="info.asankan.phonegap.smsplugin" version="0.2.0" />
  <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" version="0.2.12" />
  <vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" version="1.0.1-dev" />
  <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" version="0.3.10" />
  <vs:platformSpecificValues />
</widget>
```

This is the androidManifest of the application

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10" android:versionName="3.3.0.2" package="com.inb.xxxx" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="CordovaApp" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.plugin.gcm.PushHandlerActivity" />
        <receiver android:name="com.plugin.gcm.CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.inb.xxxx" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="22" android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.inb.xxxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.inb.xxxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

I couldn't find the solution anywhere in the net. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide your androidManifest.xml?

Comment: @ jcesarmobile I am using visual studio. Pardon me I forgot to mention that.

Comment: but the androidManifest should be generated anyway, search inside your project folders

Comment: @jcesarmobile I have added the androidManifest. Please check it.

Comment: seems ok. Are the devices where you can't install it, phones, tablets or both?

Comment: Both, but as of now I was trying only for mobiles. It works in other mobiles but it isn't in samsung devices.